# Transfer Files With Directory To SFTP Server Using Jsch

Tags: java, io, jsch

I am attempting to move files from my local machine to remote server. But i am unable to do it with JSch api.

```
for (File f : fileList) {
    channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), "/ROOT/File/"+f.getName());
}
```

i am looping my local machine directory /Home/File/file1.txt, file2,txt file3.txt and so on and save it to fileList.

I need to transfer these files to different directory in SFTP server.
say /ROOT/File/file1.txt, file2,txt file3.txt.

I do not know how to change /Home to /ROOT file path name. and also i need to copy all files without use sftpChannel.mkdir(folder); [create folder one by one] in JSch.

Comment: And the problem is? What's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 4):

"Here i do not know how to change /Home to /ROOT file path name. and also i need to copy all files without use sftpChannel.mkdir(folder); [create folder one by one] in JSch." - I don't understand this clearly. You don't want to use mkdir in code and have the directories already present? PFB sample code. you can create the ROOT directory in server before executing the code. This will loop the files in the local directory and transfer them to SFTP server..

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession("sftpuser", "sftphost");
        session.setPassword("sftppassword");
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("PreferredAuthentications",
                "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");

        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        System.out.println("sftp channel opened and connected.");
        ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        String sftpDirectory = "/target/Rootlocation";

        File directory = new File("C:\\Windows\\HomeLocation");
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();

        for (File file : fList){           
            if (file.isFile()){
                String filename=file.getAbsolutePath();
                channelSftp.put(filename, sftpDirectory, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
                System.out.println(filename + " transferred to " + sftpDirectory );
            }
        }
    }
    catch (JSchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Transfer Process Completed...");
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Siva.. if i give the full directory file path then it will create directory automatically and insert the file. if file already exists then update.

Comment: In simple words, C:/user//Home is my root directory in my local machine. /ROOT is root directory in sftp machine. eg. copying file from windows to linux.

Answer (score 1):

PFB sample code If you want to create directory automatically in remote server based on the directory names in the local machine. This will recursively check all the files in the local directory C:\user\Home and move them with same folder structure to /ROOT/ directory in linux server.. (ex: If folder1, folder2 are present along with the files in C:\user\Home, the same folder names will be created in /Root/ directory in sftp server) This will also overwrite the file, if the file is already existing in sftp server.

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ParseException
{
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = jsch.getSession("sftpuser", "sftphost");
        session.setPassword("sftppassword");
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("PreferredAuthentications",
                "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
         channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        System.out.println("sftp channel opened and connected.");
        sftpDirectory = "/ROOT/";
        NewDir=sftpDirectory;
        listf("C:\\user\\Home");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Transfer Process Completed...");
    }
public static List<File> listf(String directoryName) throws JSchException, SftpException {
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    List<File> resultList = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fList));
    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            String filename=file.getAbsolutePath();
            channelSftp.put(filename, NewDir, ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
            System.out.println(filename + " transferred to " + sftpDirectory );
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            NewDir = sftpDirectory+file.getName();
            channelSftp.mkdir(NewDir);
            System.out.println(NewDir + " Folder created ");
            resultList.addAll(listf(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }
    System.out.println(fList);
    return resultList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is convert your "File" directory into zip file and then transfer to remote server using sftp and unzip the zip file.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("C:/temp/File.zip");
            ArrayList<File> filesToAdd = new ArrayList<File>();
            File folder = new File("C:/temp/File");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            // Add files to be archived into zip file
            for (File file : listOfFiles) {
                filesToAdd.add(file);
            }
```

Then you need to converted Folder to Zip type transfer file using sftp

```
 channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream("C:/temp/File.zip"), "/ROOT/");
```

Once zip file transfered unzip it using ChannelExec.

```
ChannelExec channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");
channelExec.setCommand("unzip /ROOT/File.zip");
```

Then delete the zip file

```
channelExec.setCommand("rm /ROOT/File.zip");
```

Comment: channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream("C:/temp/File.zip"), "/ROOT/"); this does not work. The error still says - Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:/temp/File.zip (Is a directory)